# rvm cant install ruby-2.3.1

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-2.3, predix

We are working on `Setting Up Your Predix Mobile Development Environment` for this  we need `ruby`.First we  are installed  `rvm`

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Then we tried to install `ruby` like this

```
 rvm install ruby-2.3.1
```

We got Output this 
[image]

Please guide to us. Currently we are using mac :-10.11.5` OS X EI Capitian

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you google the error? Running `xcode-select --install` is the first result of a google search.

Answer (score 1):

```
rvm list known
```

should output what you can easily install

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p648]
[ruby-]2.1[.8]
[ruby-]2.2[.4]
[ruby-]2.3[.0]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have xcode command line tool? Try installing xcode. `xcode-select --install`